# Flushing the filesystem cache with a frozen filesystem

Tags: linux, mount, memory, cache

I was under the impression that dropping the cache via the `vm.drop_caches` sysctl would drop *all* caches, but when I freeze a filesystem and drop the page cache, I can still read the directory:

```
# fgrep ' /mnt ' /proc/mounts
/dev/mapper/test /mnt ext2 rw,noatime 0 0
# ls /mnt
lost+found
# fsfreeze --freeze /mnt
# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
# ls /mnt
lost+found
```

I can also read files, even after syncing:

```
# echo "hello world" > /mnt/foo
# sync
# fsfreeze --freeze /mnt
# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
# cat /mnt/foo
hello world
```

I'd like to drop the *entire* filesystem cache so that the subsequent reads (of both files and dentries) block until the filesystem is unfrozen with `fsfreeze --unfreeze /mnt`. How do I do this?

Why isn't `vm.drop_caches` doing this? Does it not drop readahead cache or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to additionally flush the block device buffers and suspend the device-mapper target rather than freezing the filesystem manually (as `dmsetup suspend` will freeze the filesystem too):

```
# ls /mnt
lost+found
# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
# blockdev --flushbufs /dev/mapper/test
# dmsetup suspend test
# ls /mnt
```

The `ls` command blocks now and will only unblock when `dmsetup resume test` is run.